# Import error supervisord

Tags: python, linux, supervisord

**My trigger.conf file looks below:**

```
[program:one_module]
environment=PYTHONPATH="/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
command=bash -c "python -u ./RealtimeAlarmModule.py"
directory=/home/harry/RealtimeDemo
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stderr_logfile=/home/harry/RealtimeDemo/supervisor.alarmmodule.err.log
stdout_logfile=/home/harry/RealtimeDemo/supervisor.alarmmodule.log
user=harry
```

I have started the supervisord via command **systemctl start supervisord**

Thereafter when I run command **supervisorctl start one_module** it gives below error : 
one_module: ERROR (abnormal termination)

Opening the supervisor.alarmmodule.err.log file states the below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./RealtimeAlarmModule.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pika
ImportError: No module named pika
```

**RealtimeAlarmModule.py** is as below:

```
import pika
import requests, json, datetime , time , sys, grequests
......
```

P.S: When I run the RealtimeAlarmModule.py as  **python RealtimeAlarmModule.py** it is working correct.  **Only while running via supervisord it gives import error**

Comment: Where is pika installed? It might not be in /root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich When I do **pip install pika** it states: 
Requirement already satisfied: pika in /root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: Add `import sys; print(sys.path)` to the top of the file, see if that is set correctly?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Above code gives the following output :  `['/root/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip', '/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7', '/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',  ** '/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages', **  '/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.5.1-py2.7.egg', '/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trollius-2.2-py2.7.egg']`

Comment: Does user harry have read access to that directory? (last thing I can think of from here)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Yes it was permission it worked. Thank you